# why is the box-shadow property not displayed properly when it is in between a button element only on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog, box-shadow

I have 2 questions.

The box-shadow property is not working properly when it is inbetween the button tag, this only happenens in safari. It works perfect on chrome, firefox, and opera. How to I get it work on safari.(I know that it works when the mouse hovers over the image.)

When I add the modal and the button I want to add it to each image, but when I add it to all the images only the first images modal pops up and the rest don't.

```
                                         Thanks for your help. :D
```

```js
// Get modal element
var modal = document.getElementById('simpleModal');
// Get open modal button
var modalBtn = document.getElementById('modalBtn');
// Get close button
var closeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('closeBtn')[0];

// Listen for open click
modalBtn.addEventListener('click', openModal);
// Listen for close click
closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
// Listen for outside click
window.addEventListener('click', outsideClick);

// Function to open modal
function openModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'block';
}

// Function to close modal
function closeModal(){
  modal.style.display = 'none';
}

// Function to close modal if outside click
function outsideClick(e){
  if(e.target == modal){
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width:90%;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  background-color:#fff;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:.5em;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.4rem 0.4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.item {
  width:25%;
  float:left;
  padding:1em;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
}

.item img:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 400ms ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

.item p {
  min-height:3em;
  /*background-color:#fff;*/
  margin:.5em 0 0 0;
  font-size:.9em;
  text-align:center;
}

.imagebtn{

}

@media screen and (max-width:1000px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:33.3%;
  }
}


@media screen and (max-width:800px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:50%;
  }

  .item p {
  font-size:.8em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px) {

/*   body {
    background-color:#fff;
  } */

  .item {
    width:100%;
  }
}

/*Modal*/
.button{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.button:hover{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

.modal{
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:1;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal-content{
  background-color:#f4f4f4;
  margin: 20% auto;
  width:70%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 7px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.17);
  animation-name:modalopen;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

.modal-header h2,
.modal-footer h3{
  margin:0;
}

.modal-header{
  background: darkgreen;
  padding:15px;
  color:#fff;
}

.modal-body{
  padding:10px 20px;
}

.modal-footer{
  background:darkgreen;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.closeBtn{
  color:#ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#fff;
}

.closeBtn:hover,.closeBtn:focus{
  color:#000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}

@keyframes modalopen{
  from{ opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
       <div class="item">
        <button id="modalBtn" class="button"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x300"></button>
        <p>Item Caption</p>
      <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla repellendus nisi, sunt consectetur ipsa velit repudiandae aperiam modi quisquam nihil nam asperiores doloremque mollitia dolor deleniti quibusdam nemo commodi ab.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300">
      <p>Item Caption</p>
      <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
            <h2>Modal Header</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla repellendus nisi, sunt consectetur ipsa velit repudiandae aperiam modi quisquam nihil nam asperiores doloremque mollitia dolor deleniti quibusdam nemo commodi ab.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Your first problem I can't comment on, as I don't have a Mac. Your second problem is because you're using duplicate IDs (`simpleModal`), which is invalid markup. Use classes instead.

Comment: @obsidian what do you mean by dublicate ID's, I know that both test divs have the same ID. there suppose to only have different images.

Comment: That's precisely what I mean. Because they both have the same ID, when you attempt to target them with JavaScript's `document.getElementById('simpleModal')`, it won't know which one you mean, and will always default to the first one. IDs **must** be unique. You'll need to make use of classes instead, like you have done for `closeBtn`.

Comment: Is there a reason for using image tag between button? You could add the box-shadow property to the button itself instead.

Comment: I am adding pictures of different types of food so each on has to be unique.